# External HDD stopped mounting automatically in Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, mount, usb-hub, berryboot

In Raspbian I used to be able to just plug in my external HDDs and they would be detected I could then find them in `/media/` using WinSCP and transfer files to them.

I haven't used Raspbian in a couple of months but now my hard drives are not mounted automatically.

I never set anything up to do this; I just got the Berryboot image and created a dual boot of Raspbian and OpenELEC.

If I do `sudo blkid` I can see the two connected drives:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1: LABEL="RECOVERY" UUID="4709-9D45" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="0001f106-01"
/dev/mmcblk0p3: LABEL="SETTINGS" UUID="b8e98431-ab33-4fb9-8933-5b3e363b715b" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="0001f106-03"
/dev/mmcblk0p5: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL="boot" UUID="06B8-2B09" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="0001f106-05" 
/dev/mmcblk0p6: LABEL="root" UUID="56f71fec-4a79-4053-b2ef-4745c54a4fc2" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="0001f106-06" 
/dev/mmcblk0p7: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="2F1B-4CCB" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="0001f106-07" 
/dev/mmcblk0p8: UUID="866e98d8-87fa-446f-8101-f2baa9287a3f" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="0001f106-08" 
/dev/sda1: LABEL="MediaOne" UUID="BE56479256474A7B" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="MediaThree" UUID="6276D81D76D7EFB1" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/mmcblk0: PTUUID="0001f106" PTTYPE="dos"
```

The only difference is now I am using the Pi hut 7 USB hub but I've connected a hard drive directly to the Pi and it still doesn't auto mount. If I boot into OpenELEC the drives are mounted perfectly.

Can anyone suggest what may have changed to be causing it to no longer mount automatically?

Comment: What versions of those OS's are you using?  I'm not famaliar with them, but Raspbian Jessie and Wheezy, for example, offer different level of support for NTFS.  Jessie, being newer, ships with ntfs-3g, so will automount a drive read-write.  Your OS's/distros may be based on an older version of Raspbian and need ntfs-3g or something.